# Does mercurial transfer full files or only diffs?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, rsync, pull

We have a 200mb file. We currently use rsync to transfer it between developers when it changes. If we include it as part of our mercurial repository, will mercurial only transfer the diff like rsync or will it transfer the full file when changed?

Comment: It's a large binary file

Answer (score 5):

Mercurial only transfers the deltas when you `hg pull`. Otherwise *distributed* version control wouldn't work at all.

When you `hg pull`, you get all the changesets missing in your local clone. Each changeset only contain a delta. The delta can be small or large, but if you're happy with the deltas found by `rsync` today, then you should also be happy with Mercurial.

About binary files: Mercurial does *not* distinguish between "text" and "binary" files when making a commit. They are all treated the same and delta compression is used in all cases. What can confuse this is that delta compression is useless if a file changes radically on every edit — the delta will be just as big as the file itself. Mercurial actually stores a compressed snapshot of the file in that case.

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that `hg incoming` also completely downloads the changeset (or the delta in this case).

Comment: As far as I know Mercurial does not store or transfer deltas for binaries. So I don’t think this answer is right in this case.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: It does make a delta, even for "binary" files. I've updated the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Several Mercurial extensions have been written for handling large files.  They work by versioning the checksum, rather than by versioning the file itself.

If you are using Mercurial 2.0 or later, then it includes the [LargeFilesExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) by default.  The docs explain how the extension works:

> The largefiles extension allows for tracking large, incompressible
>   binary files in Mercurial without requiring excessive bandwidth for
>   clones and pulls. Files added as largefiles are not tracked directly
>   by Mercurial; rather, their revisions are identified by a checksum,
>   and Mercurial tracks these checksums. This way, when you clone a
>   repository or pull in changesets, the large files in older revisions
>   of the repository are not needed, and only the ones needed to update
>   to the current version are downloaded. This saves both disk space and
>   bandwidth.

There are also other extensions you could use.  There is more information here: [Handling Large Files](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles)

Comment: Note that this is for large binary files. For large text files it may still be useful to see diffs.

Comment: +1: The largefiles extension is interesting here. You will avoid downloading versions of the large file that you don't need. So if you pull and update from revision 10 to revision 50, you only download the large file for revision 50. On the other hand, as Adam points out, it wont do any delta compression so you end up downloading the *full* version of the file as it looks in revision 50. This may end up being more or less than downloading all the deltas from 10 to 50.

Comment: Makes you wonder if a useful extension to the extension would be to use an rsync like method to do the update of the large file.

Comment: @PaulS: yeah, I think that would be very useful! It would really give you the best of both worlds.